# How to set cairo as default backend for x11() in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, cairo

I am using ggplot2 on ubuntu 12.04. By default my x11 type is set to Xlib. So when I use a smoother in qplot, I get an error like:

"semi-transparency is not supported on this device: reported only once per page".

However, if I call x11(type="cairo"), everything works fine.

How do I get cairo as the default backend for x11?

Comment: See: `options('device')`

Comment: I get the same behavior, and I think it must be a bug in `x11`. The documentation for the `type` parameter of `x11` says "The default is ‘"cairo"’ where available except on Mac OS X, otherwise ‘"Xlib"’. Clearly cairo is available, so it should be the default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define another function 'x11' which sets the proper type:

```
x11 = function (...) grDevices::x11(...,type='cairo')
```

Answer (score 13):

To make this permanent, you could add the following lines to your ~/.Rprofile file:

```
setHook(packageEvent("grDevices", "onLoad"),
function(...) grDevices::X11.options(type='cairo'))
options(device='x11')
```