# Make antialiased cairo default display for R on X11

Tags: r, ggplot2, x11

I'm trying to display ggplot graphics using cairo 2D graphics on X11. I've changed `type="cairo"` and `antialias="subpixel"` in `X11.options` and rebound my `x11` function following 
this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777008/how-to-set-cairo-as-default-backend-for-x11-in-r), but no matter what settings I start the display with, there is atrocious aliasing in my plots.

I've tried using `CairoX11` from the `Cairo` CRAN package, and while the plots look great, the device frequently segfaults bringing down my entire R process. This happens fairly reproducibly when I have two graphics devices and I make one of them full screen in my tiling window manager.

I've noticed that the graphics in R Studio look great out of box. Is there some other switch somewhere I need to view R graphics using the standard X11 device (or some other device) that look as good CairoX11 graphics, but which doesn't crash R? How does R Studio do it?

[image: default X11 produced scatterplot for faithful]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hadley changed the default shape to 19 in the latest version of ggplot2 and that fixed the issue.